# Trim the response from CURRENT_USER SQL server at a database level

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an old application that utilizes several stored procedures that attempt to save the current_user value in a "Last_Updated_By" 6-character field on several different tables and the application can only support 6-character user names.

Due to Active Directory changes the users are now COMPANY\JORDAN instead of just JORDAN so there is a truncation error when stored procedures try to update/insert the "Last_Updated_By" value.

Is there any way to override the value of CURRENT_USER at a database level to be RIGHT(CURRENT_USER,8,6) ?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't replace or overload CURRENT_USER

You need to do one of:

- change the table
- change the code
- add a trigger to update

Answer (score 1):

You could add a computed column on the table to do that. Technically, you could also rename the columns so the transition is transparent. But if you don't need to go that far, I'd just add the computed column and switch your various procs and whatnot to target that instead.

Comment: How does adding a computed column (presumably based on the existing 6 character column) solve anything? There is code storing the value of CURRENT_USER in that column; the only thing now stored in "COMPAN" (if ignoring the error). What expression do you suggest to "fix" this?

Comment: You said you wanted to effectively return `right(current_user, 8, 6)` (which now that I look at it, isn't even vaild SQL).  If all you want to do is trim off the leading 8 characters of the string BEFORE you insert it into your table, try `stuff(current_user, 1, 8, '')`